# Proving $abcd+3\geq a+b+c+d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, sum-of-squares-method

> If $a,b,c,d$ are non negatives and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=3$ prove that  $$abcd+3\ge a+b+c+d$$

The inequality is not as simple as it looks.The interesting part is that the equality occurs when $a=0,b=c=d=1$ upto permutation .(I don't know if there are further equality cases.)

I tried rewriting the inequality as $$a^2+a(bcd-1)+b^2+c^2+d^2-b-c-d\ge 0$$ As its a quadratic in $a$ it suffices to show  the discriminant$$\Delta_a={(bcd-1)}^2-4(b^2+c^2+d^2-b-c-d)\le 0$$ which unfortunately is wrong (when $a=\sqrt{3},b=c=d=0$)

P.S ;I am not aware of using Lagranges multipliers

Its from [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h266725_3__abcd_gt_a__b__c__d)

**Update** :An answer has been posted in the link above (AOPS) similar to Dr Mathva's answer

Comment: I haven't figured out how to use that but in [post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h404087p2252927) #6 arqady (I guess a.k.a. @MichaelRozenberg at MSE) seems to give a hint...

Comment: @VIVID nice find! thanks for your interest

Comment: As the problem is symmetric with respect to all variables, I tried to take $a=b=c=d=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ and got $$a b c d-(a+b+c+d)\ge \frac{9}{16}-2 \sqrt{3}\approx -2.9$$ which is the exact minimum. I don't write this as an answer because without analysis I can't prove that the minimum happens when the variables are equal.

Comment: @Raffaele interesting ,that means  this  inequality is infact  weaker......

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Yes. Pierrecarre has proved it, using real analysis methods (Lagrange multipliers). (Please edit to correctly write Lagrange's name, greatest Italian mathematician :)

Comment: -- *FYI* --
The statement holds more generally for three, or more than four real variables without positivity assumption:
$$\text{If $\,3\leqslant n\,$ and}\;\sum^n_{d=1}a_d^2=n-1,
\text{ then }\:\sum^n_{d=1}a_d\:\leqslant\:\prod^n_{d=1}a_d+n-1,$$
cf page 57 in the [GAZETA MATEMATICA](https://ssmr.ro/gazeta/gma/2020/gma3-4-2020-continut.pdf#page=57) .
Notice that $\,a_d\,$ encodes Albus Dumbledore ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Due to symmetry, assume *wlog* that $a\geqslant b\geqslant c\geqslant d\geqslant 0$. Since I will use this fact later, I am proving it before the cases:

> *Lemma:* We have that $2\geqslant a+d$.

In fact, this follows from Cauchy-Schwarz:  $$2= 2\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{3}}\geqslant 2\sqrt{\frac{a^2+3d^2}{3}}=\sqrt{1+\frac13}\cdot \sqrt{a^2+3d^2}\geqslant a+d$$

We will now consider some cases depending on the position of the number $1$:

- *Case 1*: $1\geqslant a\geqslant b\geqslant c\geqslant d\geqslant 0$. Observe that one may rewrite the inequality as $$3+abcd-(a+b+c+d)=(1-a)(1-b)+(1-c)(1-d)+(1-ab)(1-cd) $$ Which is clearly positive.
- *Case 2*: $a\geqslant 1\geqslant b\geqslant c\geqslant d\geqslant 0$. If $ab\geqslant 1$, we might proceed as in the next case. So we will work with $ab<1$. Thus \begin{align*}3+abcd-(a+b+c+d)&=(1-a)(1-b)+(1-c)(1-d)+(1-ab)(1-cd)\\&\geqslant \underbrace{(1-a)}_{<0}(1-b)+(1-c)(1-d)\\&\geqslant (1-a)(1-c)+(1-c)(1-d)\\&=(1-c)(2-(a+d))\geqslant 0  \end{align*} Where the last inequality follows from the lemma.
- *Case 3*: $a\geqslant b\geqslant 1\geqslant c\geqslant d\geqslant 0$. This implies that \begin{align*}6+2abcd-2(a+b+c+d)&=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+3+2abcd-2(a+b+c+d)\\
  &=(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(c+d-1)^2+2cd(ab-1)\geqslant 0\end{align*} Or, equivalently $3+abcd\geqslant a+b+c+d$.
- *Case 4*: $a\geqslant b\geqslant c\geqslant 1\geqslant d\geqslant 0$. As @dezdichado noticed, this case is straightforward, since it forces directly $a=b=c=1, d=0$ due to the constraint $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=3$.
- *Case 5*: $a\geqslant b\geqslant c\geqslant d\geqslant 1$. Clearly impossible, since this would yield $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\geqslant 4>3$.

Done!

Comment: your case $3$ would have forced $a = b= c = 1$ and $d = 0$ anyway due to the constraint. +1

Comment: Ingenious(+1) I doubt a better answer will be there

Comment: Thanks @AlbusDumbledore! Although I am disappointed that I could not use Michael Rozenberg's hint on aops. I thought that [Turkevichi's inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1709871p11020490) would lead somewhere, but was unable to prove that $ab+bc+cd+da+ca+bd\geqslant a+b+c+d+1$ (I am not even sure if this is true ...)

Comment: @Dr.Mathva that was my same thought of using the turkevicus inequality :) Micheal Rozenberg has surprisingly been not answering questions for the past 3 months else i am sure he would have solved the problem using  his hint:).Nevertheless this answer is worth a  bounty!

Comment: I don't think so? E.g. $a=\sqrt{3}, b=c=d=0.$ Then L.H.S. $=0$ but R.H.S. =$\sqrt{3}+1$.

Comment: @SeeHai Thanks for pointing that out; I feel so dumb to have missed it ...

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I also miss Michael Rozenberg; he's able to solve (almost) every inequality, and some of them with crazy computations (such as BW or uvw ones)!! It's sad that he does not answer questions anymore on this site (does anybody now why?). Anyway, he still comes and looks around, since he's been active at least yesterday. Hope he comes back

Comment: @Dr. Mathva please don't say so! Your solution was very nice indeed.

Comment: @Dr.Mathva :) He is still answering questions in AOPS, I am a fan of him too!

Comment: One way I was thinking of doing this problem (probably will get the best bound) was to extend the $uvw$ to a $uvwx$ for four variables, because this is useful for inequalities where the number of variables is important. But by the time I could figure out five to six base equalities to work with, your answer was up! +1

Comment: How do you say that $b^2 + c^2 + d^2 \geq 3d^2$?

Comment: I assumed wlog that $a\geqslant b\geqslant c\geqslant d$. Therefore, since the variables are positive $$b^2\geqslant d^2, c^2\geqslant d^2, d^2\geqslant d^2\implies b^2+c^2+d^2\geqslant 3d^2$$

Comment: @Dr.Mathva An answer has been posted in AOPS forum see https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h404087_inequality

Answer (score 7):

Since $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = 3$ defines a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^4$, $f(a,b,c,d)=abcd+3-a-b-c-d$ will have a global minimum and maximum over that set, that will occur (can be easily justified) in critical points of the Lagrangian
$$
L(a,b,c,d,\lambda) = abcd+3-a-b-c-d -\lambda(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-3)
$$

So, just compute the critical points, compute the value of $f$ over each of these points and get the global minimum. If the global minimum is $\ge 0$, you are done.

When computing the critical points, you will get some complex solutions, some solutions with negative components but, in the end, the relevant solutions are the ones you already mentioned and also $a=b=c=d=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. The minimum value of $f$ (even admitting negative values for $a,b,c,d$) is zero (and the maximum is $\frac{57}{16}+2\sqrt{3}$).

*Edit:* Missed one critical point, but the result stands.

Comment: sorry but what is a compact set and langrangian thing i am not at all aware

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore A compact set in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is a bounded and closed set. THis is relevant because a continuous function ($f$) always attains a global maximum and minimum values over a compact set.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Most likely, that is the [Lagrange Multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) method

Comment: The Lagrangian is the the function $L$ I defined in the post and is used as a tool to compute candidates to min/max with restrictions.

Comment: The critical points of $L$ are the  vectors $(a,b,c,d,\lambda)$ that make all the partial derivatives be zero simultaneously.

Comment: IHMO, the bulk o f Lagrange multiplier approach is **always** working on the derivatives so as to find the global extrema, which your answer didn't shed any light on. Your answer might just be a comment as VIVID posted.

Comment: @QuangHoang Providing an answer does not mean making all the calculations. I think I outlined the milestones.

Comment: My point is, yes, one doesn't need to provide all the calculations, but your answer is simply *try Lagrangian Multiplier*. It doesn't provide any further information **specific to this question** other than the generic method. E.g. Is it a straight forward process as solving a quadratic polynomial or what should OP expect from using this method to this question?

Comment: @PierreCarre This is supposed to be a contest question and such methods i am not aware even if  one is able to solve those equaions,I had also mentioned i am not ware of langranges multipliers .Any way maybe i van fathom your idea after i learn more mathematics

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I did not interpret your comment on not being aware of the method as a way of dismissing it as a solution process. I'm sure there are purely algebraic methods to solve the question and, I would gladly provide one if I had found it!

Comment: @PierreCarre OK ,thanks for your effort grateful for that!

Comment: @dezdichado No. The restriction places us in the surface of the ball. The process I proposed allows the calculation of the global max/min on the surface of the ball.

Comment: Yeaj my bad lol i confuser myself with the second derivative test

Comment: global extrema attains at **either** critical points or on boundary. Your solution did not consider boundary point, and also **did not** show that the critical point you (sort of guess) is a maximum or a minimum. The computed value is obviously larger than the case when $a=b=c=1, d=0$, which gives the minimum stated in the problem.

Comment: @QuangHoang I think you are confused about how Lagrange multipliers work. What do you think is the boundary in this case? We are computing the max/min over a set that is the surface of a sphere. Considerations about the rank of the Jacobian matrix of the restrictions allow you to say that in this case the max/min will occur on critical points. And the global max/min will be one of those.

Comment: @QuangHoang And of coarse the value on this other point will be greater than the global minumum! But it is necessary to look at this additional point to make sure that the global mimumun is attained at the other critical points.

Comment: @QuangHoang the solution is fine. Smooth function on a compact set attains its maximum and minimum in that set and they can only be achieved at a critical point. Then, you use Lagrange to find all the critical points and then find the maximum and minimum and by just looking at their values. Your concern would be valid if there happen to be an infinite number of critical points, so inspecting them individually would be hard, but it's not the case here assuming his computation is right.

Comment: $a=b=c\approx0.721545, d\approx1.19922$ and $a=b\approx0.556325, c=d\approx1.09110$ are other critical points

Answer (score 4):

This is a remark on Dr. Mathva's answer, which may seem very mysterious at first but becomes more transparent when you consider a simpler problem:

> If $a, b \geq 0$ with $a^2 + b^2 = 1$, prove that
> $$ ab+1 \geq a+b \,.$$

(It is the problem from the question if you impose $c = d = 1$.)

Here it is clear that you can factorize it as $(a-1)(b-1) \geq 0$, so you are naturally led to distinguish cases according to whether $a, b \geq 1$ or $\leq 1$. If both are $\geq 1$ or both are $\leq 1$, we are done. So suppose wlog $a \geq 1 \geq b$. Then plug in the constraint to get
$$ab + a^2+b^2 \geq a+b \,.$$
Now play a bit to recover every term in the RHS from the LHS. Because $a \geq 1$, we can just remove factors $a$ from the LHS. That is, $ab \geq b$ and $a^2 \geq a$, and we are done.

By considering this simpler problem, you can more easily get the idea of assuming wlog $a \geq b \geq c \geq d$, and of distinguishing cases according to the position of $1$.

Answer (score 3):

See, in the link below, our extension to n real variables (GMA Problem 494, page 57, with the our solution):
https://ssmr.ro/gazeta/gma/2020/gma3-4-2020-continut.pdf

---

Screenshots from the link provided:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry but link is not working for me

Comment: It's impossible. The link is valid and it's Open Access for everyone, not for Romania only.

Comment: If the issue still persists, leave me your email adress and I'll send to you the pdf.

Comment: @user120123 Just to support: the link is indeed working now.

Comment: Great. I'm glad to hear this.

Comment: @VIVID its not working for me :( says the site cat be reached

Comment: Then leave your email adress and the problem is solved.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I added the screenshots from the file if user120123 does not mind.

Comment: Great initiative. Bravo!

Comment: @VIVID wonderful thanks! and to  user120123 thanks